# How can I get a part of string with sscanf() function?

Tags: c

Currently I'm following a C book and I can not resolve one exercise. Given that I spend more than 1 day at this point, I need some help/ideas.

> "Assume that str is a string that contains a "sales rank" immediately
>   preceded by the # symbol(other characters may precede the # and/or
>   follow the sales rank). A sales rank is a series of decimal digits
>   possibly containing commas, such as the following examples:
>
> ```
> 989
> 24,675
> 1,162,620
> ```
>
> Write a call of sscanf that extracts the sales rank (but not the #
>   symbol) and stores it in a string variable named sales_rank."

What I understand that it's needed:

for example if we have:

```
     char *str = "ana are mer2,1#3lala";
```

sales_ranks should be: "2,1"

in case of:

```
     char *str = "ana ar#e mer2,1a3lala";
```

sales_ranks is an empty string.

I found here (http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/149330-getting-part-string-sscanf.html) few useful informations but it is not the correct solution.
They interpreted the exercise in a wrong approach like this:

```
     char *str = "ana are mer2,1#3lala";
```

sales_ranks is "3" which is OK but not what requested by author: "sales rank" immediately preceded by the # symbol

**EDITED:**

I misunderstood who by who is preceded. :| (So the solution exposed in the link is OK)

Actually I spend all this time to find a solution for this kind of pattern:
"{decimal}#" :)

> but it is possible and so?
>   I mean if it is possible that: # symbol immediately preceded by the "sales rank"

Comment: I think that if sales rank is immediately preceded by the # symbol, then in "2,1#3" the sales rank is 3

Comment: Yup, if the rank is preceded by # it means the sales rank comes after the #, not before.

Comment: hmmm So I misunderstood that the pattern should be "<decimal>#".
In fact that should be "#<decimal>" :?

Comment: The question is inconsistently put. You say  *"sales rank" immediately preceded by the # symbol* yet give an example `char *str = "ana are mer2,1#3lala";` with the sales rank `"2,1"` *preceding* the `'#'` symbol, ie the other way round. It's unfortunate to use an example with numbers on both sides of the `'#'` symbol. Please clarify **in the question**.

Comment: @valicfu yes, that's right.

Comment: @teppic
in this case, this question has NO sense.
It was just my confusion due my understood of English. 

(Should I delete the question? because this do not help anybody)

Comment: @valicfu - yeah probably best to delete it as it won't help anybody else :)

Comment: `char sales_ranks[16];
 if(2==sscanf(str, "%*[^,0-9]%15[,0-9]#%c", sales_ranks))
  puts(sales_ranks);`//Additional check is necessary

Comment: or.. maybe it's a best opportunity for a new challenge :)

It is possible  using sscanf to get this following type of pattern:
"<decimal>#" ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sscanf with the `%[]` and `%*` syntaxes to achieve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char sales_rank[200];
    char *str;

    sales_rank[0] = 0;
    str = "ana are mer2,1#3lala";

    sscanf(str, "%*[^#]#%199[0-9,]", sales_rank);
    printf("sales_rank=%s\n", sales_rank);

    return 0;
}
```

The `%*[^#]` will skip the chars before the `#`, ignoring them and the `%199[0-9,]` will store the sales_rank string in the variable. The matching process will stop after reading `sales_rank`. Any additional characters will be ignored.

Comment: **skip** is somewhat a misnomer. `%*[^#]` will **match** all characters except a `#` and due to the `*` following `%`, **discard** all characters matched. Any discarded matches do not increase the match count returned by `sscanf`. So yes, it will in effect **skip** all characters up to the `#`, but that's not really what it is doing. Still a good answer.

Comment: I made a slight addition to the end of the answer. Look it over and let me know if you have any objection.

Comment: @David C. Rankin. No objection of course since your precisions are pertinent.

Comment: Testing the return value of `if (1 == sscanf(...)` is certainly important here.